# Getting the values of an /AIF/ERR variant

Tags: abap

I did try using the `RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS` and `RS_VARIANT_VALUES_TECH_DATA`, it did show the values of the variant except the values of the name space, interface and interface version in which I also need to retrieve. I also searched the `VARI*` and `TVARC` tables but I didn't found it there.

I think it has something to do with the program name and screen number. Do you have any ideas or other way that I can retrieve all those values, whether using FM or select?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the parameters in the transaction `/AIF/ERR`, the ones you are talking about, vary dynamically based on the value chosen in the Application screen field. They are handled by another AIF program, and they are not saved in the program variant, but in the table `/AIF/T_ERR_VARS`.

You may call the function module `/AIF/ERR_VAR_LOAD` to load the missing parameters.
Its usage is shown in the subroutine `GET_VAR` of the program `/AIF/ERROR_HANDLING_TRANS` (which is the program behind the transaction `/AIF/ERR`).

Comment: I've checked the function module `/AIF/ERR_VAR_LOAD`  and it sure did solved my problem. Thank you!